# I want google analytics not to set cookie for IE browser alone and for other browsers I want it to set cookie

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need a help here.

As we set the google analytics tracking code, we know it starts collecting information and it also sets cookies in the browser of the user. Which will work while the same user again loads the information.

I want to find a way so that I can tell google analytics not to set cookie when it finds IE browser alone. For the rest of the browsers and OS's, it can be the same.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what are the issues with your current solution?

Comment: I see that 'User Agent' helps to know the browser information. But i'm confused on how to implement it in GA or GTM to exclude. I have created a variable in GTM, which is capturing the browser information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, are you trying to stop GA from tracking when on IE?

If so create a trigger based on that variable which is capturing browser info. Use that trigger as an exception on the GA tag when showing IE